# css multiply background image instead of one image

Tags: css, image, background

I am trying to use a image to set the background but when I put in my code I end up with multiply images instead of one whole image, I can't post a picture but here is the code i used in the CSS:

```
body { background-image:url(../images/kw4.jpeg);}
```

Am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `body { background-image:url(../images/kw4.jpeg) no-repeat;}` you may want to use `center` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

body { background:url(../images/kw4.jpeg) no-repeat;}

Answer (score 2):

If you mean multiple copies of the same image all over the page, then that is not actually a bug. When you specify a background image in CSS, your browser will automatically fill the page by tiling the same image over and over.

To prevent this from happening, add

`background-repeat: no-repeat;` to your CSS. This will render the image only once.

Comment: Also does the size of the background image matter aswell?

Comment: If your background image is large enough to cover the whole browser window (both width and height > browser width and height), then your image will not tile. However, if it is smaller either width-wise or height-wise, then yes it will tile. Using `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is your safest bet for a non-repeating background image.

Comment: I tried the background-repeat: no-repeat; but it only puts the image in the corner of my page does not cover the whole page. Would it be my other css affect the background code?

Comment: If you want the image to cover the *entire* page, you can add 
`background-size:100% 100%;` to the CSS. Beware, however, this may distort your image.

Comment: is there anyway to get a image as a background without it being distorted?